# How to add existing fragment from inside Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to open an existing fragment from compose or if i can add inside the same compose in full screen, that will also work. Also how to navigate from one existing fragment to another existing fragment from compose.

Answer (score 16):

Our recommendation for using Fragments in Compose is documented [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/interop-apis#fragments-in-compose).

Specifically, you should use the `AndroidViewBinding` composable to inflate an XML containing a `FragmentContainerView` hosting the fragment you want to use in Compose. `AndroidViewBinding` has fragment-specific handling which is why you want to use this over `AndroidView`. Note that you need to have view binding enabled for this.

Example XML file:

```xml
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/fragment_container_view"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:name="com.example.MyFragment" />
```

And then in your Composable function:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun FragmentInComposeExample() {
    AndroidViewBinding(MyFragmentLayoutBinding::inflate) {
        val myFragment = fragmentContainerView.getFragment<MyFragment>()
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Upvote for providing a link to the official docs 

Comment: How would we set an arguments bundle on the fragment before the view is inflated?

Comment: @howettl In the same boat. There does not seem to be any support for that. Chris is there any plan to add that, or perhaps some workaround?

Comment: This seems more like a band-aid and shouldn't be standard practice.  There should be a way to declare a FragmentContainerView within a Compose function or perhaps some other way of binding the view that doesn't necessitate XML declaration.  Hopefully something more elegant will be available in a future Android release.

Comment: What if I need to set custom arguments to the Fragment? Using `myFragment.arguments` not working because fragment lifecycle it's already started by FragmentContainerView.

Answer (score 6):

I solved this as following:

```
@Composable
fun ReusableFragmentComponent(
    someArgumentForFragment: FragmentArgument,
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    tag: String = "ReusableFragmentTag"
) {
    AndroidView(
        modifier = modifier,
        factory = { context ->
            FrameLayout(context).apply {
                id = ViewCompat.generateViewId()
            }
        },
        update = {
            val fragmentAlreadyAdded = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag) != null

            if (!fragmentAlreadyAdded) {
                fragmentManager.commit {
                    add(it.id, ReusableFragment.newInstance(someArgumentForFragment), tag)
                }
            }
        }
    )
}
```

In my case I called this from a fragment (hosted by navigation component), in an effort to make our reusable fragments compose compatible. I did that like so:

```
class ReusableFragments : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
            setViewCompositionStrategy(ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed)
            setContent {
                Column {
                    Text("ReusableFragment 1")
                    ReusableFragmentComponent(someArgument1, childFragmentManager, tag = "ReusableFragmentTag1")

                    Text("ReusableFragment 2")
                    ReusableFragmentComponent(someArgument2, childFragmentManager, tag = "ReusableFragmentTag2")
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

By making the tag customizable it's possible to add multiple different instances of the same fragment to the same fragment manager.

Comment: Nice, It saved my day , I just now don't worry about it.

Answer (score 5):

**Document**

- https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/migrate/interoperability-apis/views-in-compose
- https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/create#add-programmatic

**I solved this as following step:**

- you activity need extends AppCompatActivity to use fragment in the activity.
- you themes need set parent as `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar` in `res/values/themes.xml`

> ```
> <resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
>     <style name="Theme.xxx" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar"/>
> </resources>
> ```

- notice the android:theme in your activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

> ```
>     <activity android:name="com.xxx"
>             android:exported="false"
>             android:theme="@style/Theme.xxx"
>             />
> ```

- add appcompat to your build.gradle

  ```
   implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
  ```
- In compose

  ```
    AndroidView(factory = cb@{ context->
        val view = FragmentContainerView(context)
        view.id = ViewCompat.generateViewId()
        val selfId = view.id
        supportFragmentManager.commit {
            setReorderingAllowed(true)
            add<MyFragment>(selfId)
        }
        return@cb view
    })
  ```
- full activity kt file

  ```
    package com.xxx

    import android.os.Bundle
    import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    import androidx.compose.ui.viewinterop.AndroidView
    import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat
    import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    import androidx.fragment.app.commit
    import androidx.fragment.app.add
    import com.xxx.MyFragment

    class demoFragmentActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContent{
                AndroidView(factory = cb@{ context->
                    val view = FragmentContainerView(context)
                    view.id = ViewCompat.generateViewId()
                    val selfId = view.id
                    supportFragmentManager.commit {
                        setReorderingAllowed(true)
                        add<MyFragment>(selfId)
                    }
                    return@cb view
                })
            }
        }
    }
  ```

Comment: This should be the correct answer to the authors question, I don't get it why the others have upvotes when none of them is working as expected.

Comment: While I couldn't get it to compile as-is, this answer was definitely the only helpful out there

Comment: where do we get the supportFragmentManger?

Comment: @Arul I have add all imports this code referenced.
supportFragmentManger is 
 `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity#getSupportFragmentManager`.

Answer (score 1):

This helped me:

```
@Composable
fun MyFragmentView(
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    AndroidView(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        factory = { context ->
            val containerId = R.id.container // some unique id
            val fragmentContainerView = FragmentContainerView(context).apply {
                id = containerId
            }

            val fragment = MyFragment()
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(containerId, fragment, fragment.javaClass.simpleName)
                .commitAllowingStateLoss()

            fragmentContainerView
        }
    )
}
```

ids.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="container" type="id"/>
</resources>
```