# Adding Google Maps (MapFragment) Fragment inside Jetpack Compose project

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-jetpack-compose

I want to add Google Maps to my Jetpack Compose map, but the current Jetpack Compose Google Maps are not completed for my use case. Therefore I want to embed the existing Fragments, which have more functionality, inside my Jetpack Compose project.

This is my `Composable fun`, I get a NPE and I don't know how to proceed. I don't have any `.xml` files and I prefer to work without them:

```
@Composable
fun GoogleMapsWrapper() {
    val myFragment = remember {
        MapFragment()
    }

    AndroidView(factory = { _ ->
        myFragment.view!! // This gives the NPE
    })
}
```

Comment: see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69943010/how-to-add-existing-fragment-from-inside-compose

Answer (score 1):

I could not find any way to use fragments inside a composable without any xml file, you would have to create one xml file containing FragmentcontainerView in it.

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.example.compose.snippets.interop.MyFragment" />
```

Use the AndroidViewBinding composable to add a Fragment in Compose. AndroidViewBinding has fragment-specific handling such as removing the fragment when the composable leaves the composition.

```
@Composable
fun FragmentInComposeExample() {
    AndroidViewBinding(MyFragmentLayoutBinding::inflate) {
        val myFragment = fragmentContainerView.getFragment<MyFragment>()
        
    }
}
```

Comment: also read the documentation https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/migrate/interoperability-apis/views-in-compose#:~:text=InteroperabilityAPIsSnippets.kt-,Fragments%20in%20Compose,the%20composable%20leaves%20the%20composition.