# Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id In AndroidViewBinding Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, fragment, android-viewbinding, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I am loading a fragment inside Jetpack Compose AndroidViewBinding as shown below,

```
val fragmentManager = (LocalContext.current as? FragmentActivity)?.supportFragmentManager
AndroidViewBinding(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    factory = { inflater, parent, attachToParent ->
        val binding = ConsumerOdrdGoogleMapLayoutBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, attachToParent)
        val consumerOdrdFragment = ConsumerODRDMapFragment.newInstance("test")
        fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()
            ?.replace(binding.consumerSdkFragmentContainer.id, consumerOdrdFragment, TAG)
            ?.commitAllowingStateLoss()
        binding
    }
)
```

I am getting below mentioned crash in some edge cases and I am not able to reproduce the issue to resolve this.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0900cf (com.app.myapp.staging:id/consumer_sdk_fragment_container) for fragment ConsumerODRDMapFragment{51aa5f7} (3f2e436a-01b1-48a0-a96e-600816efdab8 id=0x7f0900cf tag=ConsumerODRDMapView)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:513)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1840)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1758)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1701)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:488)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

Comment: You can check here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69943010/how-to-add-existing-fragment-from-inside-compose)